# SQL to calculate age based on year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get a list of names who are turning 14 year old and 11 months. Can someone to help me fix the SQL below?  Thanks!

```
SELECT NAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE
(cast(datediff(DAY, DOB, getDate() -1) /(365.23076923074) as int)>=14 
    AND cast(datediff(MONTH, DOB, getDate() -1) % (12) as int)>=11)
OR      
(cast(datediff(DAY, DOB, getDate() -1) /(365.23076923074) as int)<=15 
    AND cast(datediff(MONTH, DOB, getDate() -1) % (12) as int)<=0)
```

Comment: Can't you simply check if DOB date is lower than  `dateadd(month, - (12 * 14 + 11 ), getdate())` **and** higher than `dateadd(year, -15 , getdate())` ?

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These people turn 14, 11 months, today.

```
select name 
from table
where DOB = cast(dateadd(mm,-11,dateadd(yy,-14,getdate())) as date)
--this is to eliminate the time on getdate
```

Comment: how so? anyone born on 9/10/2001 would have been returned. Do you have anyone born on that day?

Comment: is your DOB field of type DATE? if it's varchar you'll need to CAST it with `where CAST(DOB as DATE) = ...`

Comment: DOB is Datetime type. I did not get any names.

Comment: Then no one was born 14 years and 11 months ago from today. Check your data @Ice

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need `<=` or just `<`. Please make changes accordingly.

```
select NAME from table    Where DOB < = DATEADD(MONTH, -179, GETDATE())
```

Or If you are just looking for results between a span of one month then:

```
select NAME from table Where DOB BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -179, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -180, GETDATE())
```

Comment: @Ice if it works can you please mark it as an answer?